# AWS ECS CLI verification failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am a beginner for AWS ECS.
I was following the steps given on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI_installation.html
but I could not verify the signature.
[image]

I do have the ecs-cli.asc file at C:\Windows\System32 location
[image]

I am not sure what's wrong. I am executing command prompt and Windows power shell as administrator.
Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

After adding full path.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried with full path?

Comment: Yes i tried with full path as well. But anyways the ecs-cli.asc file is on same C:\Windows\System32 location.
Added screenshot.

Comment: @Mr.Jain did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

After putting the ecs-cli.asc file in the same directory as the ecs-cli (C:\Program Files\Amazon\ECSCLI) and then changing the command to gpg --verify ecs-cli.asc ecs-cli.exe, it worked.

Comment: I tried this, but still getting the same error. From which location are you running the command?